# What is the reason behind implementing redux store as a function, not a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, redux

Last day I was trying to write a wrapper around Redux store but I had to copy and paste some code in order to create the same API. With react I could easily extend my class from `React.Component` so I was thinking why developers of Redux have not implemented their store like this?
here is copy of the store code:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js

Answer (score 2):

Because you can use `enhancer`s instead, which allow you to compose multiple functions with the store in the particular order you want. Using inheritance would require that all your third party enhancers inherit from each other in the order you need them to.

Comment: What if I want to overwrite a method of store like dispatch? is it possible to do that with enhancers?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, if you look at the `applyMiddleware` enhancer included with Redux, you'll see it does exactly that.  See https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js#L30 , which defines a new function that wraps around the "real" `dispatch`, and then exposes that function as the "new" `dispatch` that everyone would call.